# Pivoting a data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How do I pivot the following data frame, so as to have one column per weekday?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.date_range('2018-01', '2018-12', name='date')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(len(idx)), index=idx, columns=['value'])
df['weekday'] = idx.weekday
```

I've tried the following, and whilst there is one column per weekday, there are a lot of `NaN` values. This is because the data frame's index is used by the pivoted data frame.

```py
pivoted = df.pivot(columns='weekday', values='value')
pivoted.head()
# weekday            0         1         2       3         4   5   6
# date                                                              
# 2018-01-01  0.638018       NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN NaN NaN
# 2018-01-02       NaN  0.179721       NaN     NaN       NaN NaN NaN
# 2018-01-03       NaN       NaN  0.713559     NaN       NaN NaN NaN
# 2018-01-04       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.2092       NaN NaN NaN
# 2018-01-05       NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN  0.679759 NaN NaN
```

Ultimately, I'd like box plots of the values per weekday. The following works, because the `NaN` values are ignored.

```py
pivoted.plot.box()
```

Surely, there's a way that doesn't involve a lot of `NaN` values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a boxplot by weekday you don't need to pivot. Just call boxplot:

```
df.boxplot(column='value', by='weekday')
```

[image]

Comment: The parsimonious answers are the best answers. Thank you!